# How to filter HTML elements based on their css attribute values ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For example I want to select all the elements that have text-align= left , is there any plugin do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this plugin that do the job

```
$("li:css(text-align,left)").remove () ;
```

https://github.com/sam12github/JCSS

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('text-align') == 'left';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

css3 attribute selector : `$('[text-align=left]')`